# Understanding details of Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: ios5, apple-push-notifications

Is it true that we can use any component for our own server component? I mean it can be a Java or C# TCP/IP client which connects with Apple servers to push notifications. This can also be a console application, is that right?

Also, is it right that we have to push notifications for APN server, with each and every deviceTokens registered on our own server?

Comment: you said you had an issue, but I dont see any issue, is there something that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever language you want and you will have to send push notifications for every registered device token. You should also investigate apple's feedback API's which you should periodically check to see which of your devices are no longer registered because sending a push has no feedback and you will not know if it is being received or not. If you use a service such as Urban Airship the setup will be much much easier to start and they have helpful API's to give them a group of device tokens or to do a mass push to all registered device tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on both accounts.  You can write your own method to send it, and you must send it to each device id.

framework that might help you:
http://www.easyapns.com/